# How to show that any subgroup of $S_n$ of index two contains all cyclic permutations of length three?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. How to show that any subgroup of $S_n$ of index two contains all cyclic permutations of length three? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every subgroup $N\leq G$ with index $2$ is bound to be normal.

Every cyclic permutation of length $3$ can be written as a quadrate.

E.g. $\left(123\right)=\left(132\right)^{2}$.

Consequently if $N\leq S_n$ has index $2$ then in quotient group $S_n/N$ we have: $$\left(123\right)N=\left(132\right)^{2}N=\left[\left(132\right)N\right]^{2}=N$$
This means exactly that $\left(123\right)\in N$.

Comment: thank you very much. Where do we use the condition $|S_n/N|=2$? Why $[(132)N]^2=N$?

Comment: I see. Since $|S_n/N|=2$, $[(132)N]^2=N$.

Comment: Indeed. In general if $N$ is normal and has index $n$ then $g^nN=(gN)^n=N$ for each $g\in G$, proving that $N$ contains every $n$-power $g^n$.

Comment: Your third comment is (almost) a duplicate of the first ;). You are very welcome.